# Display an image into windows forms

Tags: c#

I wanted to display an image to the windows forms, but i already did this and the image did not come out.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the code:

```
private void Images(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
    pb1.Image = Image.FromFile("../SamuderaJayaMotor.png");
    pb1.Location = new Point(100, 100);
    pb1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
    this.Controls.Add(pb1);
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code you posted that we can see or check.  Post more code.

Answer (score 17):

Here (http://www.dotnetperls.com/picturebox) there 3 ways to do this:

- Like you are doing.
- Using ImageLocation property of the PictureBox like:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();            
      pb1.ImageLocation = "../SamuderaJayaMotor.png";
      pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
  }
  ```
- Using an image from the web like:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();            
      pb1.ImageLocation = "http://www.dotnetperls.com/favicon.ico";
      pb1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
  }
  ```

And please, be sure that "../SamuderaJayaMotor.png" is the correct path of the image that you are using.

Comment: hai winner crespo, i already did that and the image was loaded to the form, but the image did not show anything, just sign "x", i already check the name file and i change the path to "SamuderaJayaMotor.png" and include that image to the project folder, but when i run, it is still sign "x"

Comment: I have proved and the problem is the path. May be you can prove using "../../SamuderaJayaMotor.png" because if you use System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath and debug you will see that the StartupPath is "bin/debug/" then you need to go back two folders.

Comment: You can see an example here https://github.com/wistcc/Stackoverflow-answers/tree/master/DisplayImage

Comment: @Kaoru you may want to call your `Images` function by adding this line `Images(this, null);` on any click event or main function as dotNET mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

There could be many reasons for this. A few that come up quickly to my mind:

1. Did you call this routine AFTER `InitializeComponent()`?
2. Is the path syntax you are using correct? Does it work if you try it in the debugger? Try using backslash (\) instead of Slash (/) and see.
3. This may be due to side-effects of some other code in your form. Try using the same code in a blank Form (with just the constructor and this function) and check.

Answer (score 1):

I display images in windows forms when I put it in Load event like this:

```
    private void Form1_Load( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
        pictureBox1.ImageLocation = "./image.png"; //path to image
        pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.AutoSize;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PictureBox pb = new PictureBox();
        pb.Location = new Point(0, 0);
        pb.Size = new Size(150, 150);
        pb.Image = Image.FromFile("E:\\Wallpaper (204).jpg");
        pb.Visible = true;
        this.Controls.Add(pb);
    }
```