# C# button click, show image and then exit

Tags: c#

I have been programming a `button_Click` event, where I need the following:

1. Set visibility of a gif to true (in picture box, was false at first)
2. Wait one second with the picture shown (its a gif and I need it moving, which means `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` will stop the animation)
3. Exit program

I have this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loading.Visible = !loading.Visible;
        // pause for a second, then exit
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display an image into windows forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193745/display-an-image-into-windows-forms)

Comment: Actually not. Visibility is solved, the comment is a TODO.

Comment: Please use "google", look at some tutorials how to do that (there are plenty of them). Your code doesn't show really anything related to what you are requesting.

Comment: which part is not working? you can simply add System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

Comment: I cannot, `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` will stop the animation of a GIF.

Comment: Just use a timer (its in the toolbox, google C# timer). Not clear what your question is. What do you need help with? The 1 second delay? Showing the GIF? Closing the application?

Comment: 1 second delay without affecting the GIF animation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the following:

```
//      ↓↓↓↓↓ << notice the `async` keyword.
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    loading.Visible = !loading.Visible;
    // Wait for one second.
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    Application.Exit();
}
```

The [`Task.Delay()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) does the following:

> Creates a task that will complete after a time delay.

And using the `await` keyword, we *asynchronously* wait for the task to complete. "asynchronously" means that the current thread (the UI thread in this case) will not be blocked. Therefore, the animation will not be affected.

Comment: Thats exactly what i wanted. Thank you!

Comment: The answer by @ICloneable will work just fine and there is nothing wrong with that answer, but I would just use a timer if it were me. Much simpler in my opinion.

Comment: @Jesse If a timer is what you're comfortable with, that's fine, but how is using a timer "much simpler" than simply adding one line of code (i.e., `await Task.Delay(1000);`) to your method? The usual use case for timers is when you have a _recurring_ event (i.e., you want to repeat some action over and over at a regular interval).

Comment: @ICloneable Maybe the word "much" is too strong. Nothing wrong with your answer (in fact I upvoted it). Just my opinion.